# Creating 'dynamic' DataTemplates at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml

I currently have a situation where templates for the cells of a DataGrid are created at runtime because the property names are dynamic and not known at design time. For example the "ColumnName" is used here (from a DataColumn) as the path for the Binding to get a colour to fill an ellipse:

```
                       myCellTemplate = "<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""> " &
                                       "<Ellipse Width=""25"" Height=""25"" Margin=""0,3"" Stroke=""Black"" StrokeThickness=""1"" " &
                                       "Fill=""{Binding [" & myColumn.ColumnName & "], Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}""></Ellipse></DataTemplate>"
```

Is there any way I can achieve the same but have my DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary instead of in code behind? Being able to edit the templates in the usual manner would be much more preferable.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing the dynamic value to the converter? If so, how do you plan to use them in the converter? Do you know of the possible values that would be used?

Comment: You could treat the template defined in XAML as a plain string or XML and perform a replace one way or another. But there is no "WPF specific way" of simply replacing a part of a template that you have defined in XAML programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML is XML and hence you can manipulate it as such or you can load it as a string and use string manipulation.
That's a bit of a nuisance once it's compiled into baml.
BUT a resource dictionary can be loaded from a "flat" uncompiled file.
You can have an uncompiled resource dictionary if localappdata and manipulate it.
There are a number of samples which do that sort of thing linked here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx

Or you could include a piece of xaml in a txt file and manipulate that.
In the suite I'm working on I have such a txt file which contains:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Factor[^^^Index^^^], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"  
 xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UILib;assembly=UILib"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScenarioEditor"
 xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ModelLib;assembly=ModelLib"
>

        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ui:IconParent Height="20" Width="30" 
                        ui:IconParent.IPType="{x:Static model:UnitTypes.^^^EnumString^^^}"
                        ui:Icon.UnitType="{x:Static model:UnitTypes.^^^EnumString^^^}"
                        ui:Icon.Side="{Binding DataContext.DefenderSide
                            , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                        >
                    <ui:IconParent.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>
                            ^^^EnumDescription^^^
                        </ToolTip>
                    </ui:IconParent.ToolTip>
                        <ui:UnitIcon Margin="2"/>
                </ui:IconParent>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I then build a datagrid using this code:

```
XElement col = GetXElement(@"pack://application:,,,/Views/AttackFactors/attackFactorColumn.txt");
foreach (UnitTypes ut in  Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitTypes)).Cast<UnitTypes>().Where(x=>x.ThisFights()==true).Select(x=>x).ToList())
{
    XElement el = new XElement(col);
    string colString = el.ToString()
        .Replace("^^^Index^^^", ((int)ut).ToString())
        .Replace("^^^EnumString^^^", ut.ToString())
        .Replace("^^^EnumDescription^^^", ut.ToDescriptionString());
    ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    DataGridTextColumn tc = (DataGridTextColumn)XamlReader.Parse(colString, context);
    dg.Columns.Add(tc);
};
```

You could extend that principle to build a resource dictionary merged at design time so you could see the effect against design time data.

Design time only resource dictionaries:
https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/WPF-Design-Time-Support-(Part-2)

Comment: Although I was hoping for a way to have my "dynamic" resource dictionary available in more of a straight forward way, your idea has put me in the right direction so eliminating having to edit XAML in code-behind concatenated string variables.

Much obliged to you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create Cell Templates dynamically is to set a `ContentControl` for your Cell Template and within the `Style.Triggers` for your `ContentControl` set multiple DataTriggers that check for a property (in your case the "ColumnName").

From there you can set the `template` property of the `ContentControl` to any `ControlTemplate` of your choosing, and store them in a `ResourceDictionary`

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColumnName}" Value="Name1">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Template1}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColumnName}" Value="Name2">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Template2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    ...

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```